# mysql count distinct positive values but count all -1 values in table and give total?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table called ptb_profile_views that looks like this:

```
id | profile_id | viewed_profile_id
1        2              6
2        2              6
3        3              6
4       -1              6
5       -1              6
```

i have been trying to count the positive values in 'profile_id' only once as distinct values and count -1 values as many times as they appear with the following query:

```
function check_profile_views3() {
global $connection;
global $_SESSION;
$query = "
SELECT id,profile_id,viewed_profile_id COUNT
FROM ptb_profile_views 
WHERE profile_id > 0
GROUP BY profile_id
UNION
/*shows all -1 profile id's*/
SELECT id,profile_id,viewed_profile_id 
FROM ptb_profile_views 
WHERE profile_id <= 0";
$check_profile_views_set3 = mysql_query($query, $connection);
confirm_query($check_profile_views_set3);
return $check_profile_views_set3;       
        }
```

so the end result is

```
2, 3, -1, -1
```

but instead of echoing out the actual values them selves i want the query to do a count of the values.

so...

```
2, 3, -1, -1 = a total of 4
```

i am also trying to call the query like so which i don't know if will work:

```
$check_profile_views_set3 = check_profile_views3();
while ($views3 = mysql_fetch_array($check_profile_views_set3)) { 

echo "".$views3['profile_id'].""; ?>
```

can someone please show me how i can do this? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a + b AS TotalCount
FROM
        (
          SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT profile_ID) a
          FROM   ptb_profile_views
          WHERE  profile_ID > 0
        ) x,
        (
          SELECT COUNT(profile_ID) b
          FROM   ptb_profile_views
          WHERE  profile_ID < 0
        ) y
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95379/8)

Comment: is it possible to add a condition to say AND profile_id!=".$_SESSION['user_id']."